# let f: C00 -> R be a linear function, let f(en) = n. Prove if the sequence (n) is bounded, then f is continuous with respect to ||.||1

Tags: real-analysis

I already have an outline,

Suppose n is bounded, then ∃M∈R s.t. ||n||1 ≤M.

Assume that en→e in C00.

Let ɛ>0

Then ∃N such that ∀n≥N ∃||en-e||1<...

Then ||f(en)-f(e)||1=..... <ɛ.

I don't know what to fill in those spaces.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your mathematics.

Comment: Sorry it is first time using this website, could you please help me on this problem?